# Conflicts between Snakemake and GROMACS?

Tags: bash, shell, slurm, snakemake

I tried to simplify my issue as much as possible and still getting the error.

The whole idea is that I want to execute (inside a much more complex workflow) the command:
`gmx mdrun -nt 12 -deffnm emin -cpi` on a cluster. For that I have a conda environment with GROMACS and Snakemake.

On a traditional way I have the jobscript (`traditional_job.sh`) with:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=uds-hub 
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12 
#SBATCH --mem=5000
#SBATCH --time=15:00
#SBATCH --job-name=reproduce_error
#SBATCH --output=reproduce_error.o
#SBATCH --error=reproduce_error.e

gmx mdrun -nt 12 -deffnm emin -cpi
```

And everything works as expected after `sbatch traditional_job.sh`. However, if I try to use Snakemake instead, the problems start.

My `Snakefile` is:

```py
rule gmx:
    input:
        tpr = "emin.tpr"
    output:
        out = 'emin.gro'
    shell:
        '''
           gmx mdrun -nt 12 -deffnm emin -cpi
        '''
```

And my `job.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
snakemake \
    --jobs 10000 \
    --verbose \
    --debug-dag \
    --latency-wait 50 \
    --cluster-cancel scancel \
    --rerun-incomplete \
    --keep-going \
    --cluster '
        sbatch \
        --partition=uds-hub \
        --nodes=1 \
        --cpus-per-task=12 \
        --mem=5000 \
        --time=15:00 \
        --job-name=reproduce_error \
        --output=reproduce_error.o \
        --error=reproduce_error.e '
```

After `./job.sh`, the GROMACS's error (written out on `reproduce_error.e`) is:

```
Program:     gmx mdrun, version 2022.2-conda_forge
Source file: src/gromacs/taskassignment/resourcedivision.cpp (line 220)

Fatal error:
When using GPUs, setting the number of OpenMP threads without specifying the
number of ranks can lead to conflicting demands. Please specify the number of
thread-MPI ranks as well (option -ntmpi).

For more information and tips for troubleshooting, please check the GROMACS
website at http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Errors
```

I observed that in the output of `snakemake` is written a different shell (`#!/bin/sh`). But honestly, I do not know if that could be the problem, neither how to solve it if that is the case:

```bash
Jobscript:
#!/bin/sh
# properties = {"type": "single", "rule": "gmx", "local": false, "input": ["emin.tpr"], "output": ["emin.gro"], "wildcards": {}, "params": {}, "log": [], "threads": 1, "resources": {"mem_mb": 1000, "mem_mib": 954, "disk_mb": 1000, "disk_mib": 954, "tmpdir": "<TBD>"}, "jobid": 0, "cluster": {}}
cd '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce error' && /home/uds_alma015/.conda/envs/abfe/bin/python3.9 -m snakemake --snakefile '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce error/Snakefile' --target-jobs 'gmx:' --allowed-rules 'gmx' --cores 'all' --attempt 1 --force-use-threads  --resources 'mem_mb=1000' 'mem_mib=954' 'disk_mb=1000' 'disk_mib=954' --wait-for-files '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce error/.snakemake/tmp.lfq5jq4u' 'emin.tpr' --force --keep-target-files --keep-remote --max-inventory-time 0 --nocolor --notemp --no-hooks --nolock --ignore-incomplete --rerun-triggers 'software-env' 'params' 'input' 'mtime' 'code' --skip-script-cleanup  --conda-frontend 'mamba' --wrapper-prefix 'https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/' --latency-wait 50 --scheduler 'ilp' --scheduler-solver-path '/home/uds_alma015/.conda/envs/abfe/bin' --default-resources 'mem_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)' 'disk_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)' 'tmpdir=system_tmpdir' --mode 2 && touch '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce error/.snakemake/tmp.lfq5jq4u/0.jobfinished' || (touch '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce error/.snakemake/tmp.lfq5jq4u/0.jobfailed'; exit 1)
```

P.s. ChatGPT goes in circle with this question :-)

### Update

I even isolate more the error. The following `other_job.sh` (submitted to the cluster as `sbatch other_job.sh`) script also gave the same error:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=uds-hub 
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12 
#SBATCH --mem=5000
#SBATCH --time=15:00
#SBATCH --job-name=reproduce_error
#SBATCH --output=reproduce_error.o
#SBATCH --error=reproduce_error.e

/home/uds_alma015/.conda/envs/abfe/bin/python3.9 -m snakemake --snakefile '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce_error/Snakefile' --target-jobs 'gmx:' --allowed-rules 'gmx' --cores 'all' --attempt 1 --force-use-threads  --resources 'mem_mb=1000' 'mem_mib=954' 'disk_mb=1000' 'disk_mib=954' --wait-for-files '/home/uds_alma015/GIT/BindFlow/ideas/reproduce_error/.snakemake/tmp.mqan6qbp' 'emin.tpr' --force --keep-target-files --keep-remote --max-inventory-time 0 --nocolor --notemp --no-hooks --nolock --ignore-incomplete --rerun-triggers 'mtime' 'software-env' 'params' 'code' 'input' --skip-script-cleanup  --conda-frontend 'mamba' --wrapper-prefix 'https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/' --latency-wait 50 --scheduler 'ilp' --scheduler-solver-path '/home/uds_alma015/.conda/envs/abfe/bin' --default-resources 'mem_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)' 'disk_mb=max(2*input.size_mb, 1000)' 'tmpdir=system_tmpdir' --mode 2
```

And this is the command build by `snakemake`. It looks like that command does not interact (in some how) with the definitions of `SBATCH`. But still not sure.

Comment: How are you calling `snakemake`?

Comment: With ./job.sh. and the content of job.sh is on the description of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with snakemake, but with a different program. In the end I had to specifically unset some environment variables, because snakemake sets them for each instantiated shell. In particular `OMP_NUM_THREADS` was the root cause of my problem.

Make sure to compare which environment variables are set within snakemake and in your regular script, this might give you a hint to find the culprit variable.

Comment: While your answer seems legitimate, I encourage you to clearly provide the command to unset the variable and to avoid the questions. You can rephrase: "make sure to compare which environment…". This will avoid others to think you're asking a follow up question and flag your answer ;)

Comment: Indeed, some environmental variables were the root of my issues. When I `unset` those variables before the execution of GROMACS, things start to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread searching for a combi of gromacs and snakemake.

First, snakemake meanwhile supports slurm, see https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cluster.html . There is no need any more to write

> --cluster ...

Also, the separation between conda and cluster modules should work. I would fear that gromacs with gpu and / or MPI-bindings cannot not easily be integrated in conda. So, if this is still an issue, try

> snakemake --use-envmodules

Be aware: snakemake is the job shepherd. There is no use running snakemake in a jobscript, rather snakemake spawns jobs (unless excluded with the `localrules` directive.

I hope this helps, after all this time.

Then, are you actively developing a workflow to support gromacs? It would be wonderful to see a repo!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35111036)

Comment: The opposite is true: with the current version of the workflow manager - as pointed out and apparent from the linked documentation - the "asker" is relieved of the necessity of issuing the `--cluster` flag, all of his additional code. The workflow manager can spawn the jobs as intended on the mentioned batch system. No further clarification was asked for.

I apologize for the expression of hope to see more of the code. This is rather an expression of enthusiasm than asking for clarification, too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).